# python find duplicate lists in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am using python 2.7 and I am trying to find duplicate lists in list of lists based on two values. 
For example

```
list= [[a,x,y,2], [b,xx,yy,2], [c,xxx,yyy,3],[a,yx,yx,2]]

outcome [[a,xyx,yyx,2], [b,xx,yy,2], [c,xxx,yyy,3]]
```

so based on the values a and 2, join the other values

any suggestions??

thank you
best regards

Comment: What solutions did you already try? Maybe this module can help you: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools

Comment: The answers of that previous question should work perfectly for this one too. In brief: iterate over the outer list, make a tuple of the first and last values from the inner list, then check if that tuple is in a set of seen pairs.

Comment: @Blckknght -- This is slightly different.  Here, OP wants to merge the lists so a `dict` is more appropriate than a `set` as the dict gives you an easy handle on the list that you want to merge with.

Comment: @mgilson: Ah, I see. I didn't read carefully enough and missed the `xyx` and `yyx` bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
lis =  [['a','x','y',2], ['b','xx','yy',2], ['c','xxx','yyy',3],['a','yx','yx',2]]
dic = OrderedDict()
for x in lis:
   key = (x[0],x[-1])
   if key not in dic:
      dic[key] = x[1:-1]
   else:
      val =  dic[key]
      dic[key] = [a+b for a,b in zip(val,x[1:-1])]

print [[k[0]] + v + [k[1]] for k,v in dic.items()]
```

**output:**

```
[['a', 'xyx', 'yyx', 2], ['b', 'xx', 'yy', 2], ['c', 'xxx', 'yyy', 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use a dict if order doesn't matter:

```
from operator import itemgetter
getter = itemgetter(0,-1)

def merge(lst1,lst2):
    return [lst1[0],lst1[1]+lst2[1],lst1[2]+lst2[2],lst1[3]]


d = {}
for sublist in lst:
    t = getter(sublist)
    if t not in d:
       d[t] = sublist
    else:
       d[t] = merge(sublist,d[t])

print d.values()
```

If the order matters, you could use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: It should be `(0, -1)`

Comment: @jamylak -- right you are.  I spent a little longer than usual working with Fortran yesterday afternoon.  Apparently I forgot to switch my mind all the way back into 0-indexing. :)

Comment: where is you find fortran legacy product in 2013?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry -- I'm a scientist until the end of this month.  We still use Fortran a lot. :).  (And, FWIW, I think that Fortran is actually a pretty neat language -- Amazingly simple and clean syntax for array operations.  A lot of the stuff in numpy (array slicing for example) is borrowed from Fortran syntax.)

Comment: Not quite what I want but will come handy soon :) thanx

Comment: Did you use R? what is your expressions about?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry -- I've never used `R`.  Only Fortran, C, Python and various sh/bash utilities for me (so far)